# How do I step into one of my included libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I step into a routine that is contained in my library module, I see the following:

```
public void ProcessClick(android.widget.Button Key, boolean bAutoProcess) { /* compiled code */ }
```

How do I configure my module to not only include the library, but its source as well so I can step into it?

Comment: Attach source zip/folder to dependencies as well.

Comment: @user117 that worked, if you put it in an answer I'll accept it

Comment: No need. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry for the erroneous close vote - misread and thought you were talking about Android sources rather than those of your own lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per SD:

> Attach source zip/folder to dependencies as well

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit please? It's pretty sparse right now.